# How to copy full folder of 3rd Party dependencies to Test running directory?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am working with a 3rd Party API, they require a ridiculous amount of references.
About 60 dlls and another subfolder with 6 more dlls. The folder structure is something like:

- Libs

  - dlls
  - Subfolder

    - More dlls

**How can I make Visual Studio copy all those dlls with the subfolder and additional dlls inside, to the Test run folder?**

My application references only about 6 of those dlls, but then they need all the rest for Licensing issues, etc. So when I run my application, I use xcopy to copy all those files to the bin folder and the Application runs.

But I am not sure how to go about copying the those files for my tests.
Right now I have this xcopy in my Tests Project:

```
set  librariesToReference="$(SolutionDir)..\Libs\"
set Target="$(TargetDir)"
xcopy /D /Y /I /G /R /E %librariesToReference%* %Target%
```

And of course the Tests fail because the third party dependencies don't have everything they need in the folder where tests are run.

I read about the Deployment Items, but it doesn't seem practical to name every single file I need in a `DeploymentItem`.

Also, the dlls need to be flat in the output folder, so they are not organized inside a folder, so I don't have a folder to create a `DeploymentItem` for "it"

Comment: putting that xcopy into your test solutions post-build step should do what you want. Where did you put it?

Comment: @Sors - I put it in the post-build of my Test solution and the test fail. They are not finding the vendor dlls are not finding the additional dlls they need.

Comment: then your problem probably is a faulty xcopy. did script verify it manually?

Comment: @Sors - The files are being copied to the `MyTests\bin\Debug` folder. The problem is that then they are not copied to the folder where from the Tests are run.

Comment: `MyTests\bin\Debug` and `MyTests\bin\Release` should be the folders your tests are run from usually. Where are your tests run from?

Comment: @Sors - Tests are run from a [Test Deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms182474(v=vs.80).aspx) folder, that is why many people have issues when they need specific file deployment. Temporarily I am using a .runsettings configuration and setting `DeploymentEnabled` to `false` [so the tests are run from the bin folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475.aspx), however every other test we have is running from the **Test Deployment folder** and I need this ones to run from there also.

Comment: In that case i don't see any alternative to using deployment items. You could add them via script to your runsettings in the pre-build step. you can also specify the output directory to the testdirectory in each deployment item xml definition, so you have them flat.